# Не компилируется Busybox

Tags: linux, makefile

Собираю свой Linux дистрибутиив, хочу поставить Busybox. К сожалению, при компиляции *занятой коробки* выдаёт данную ошибку:

```
loginutils/login.c:81:11: fatal error: security/pam_appl.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
   81 | # include <security/pam_appl.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:198: loginutils/login.o] Ошибка 1
make: *** [Makefile:743: loginutils] Ошибка 2
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Видимо нужны development-файлы для PAM (в готовых дистрибутивах это [pam-devel](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=/usr/include/security/pam_appl.h) или [libpam0g-dev](https://packages.debian.org/ru/sid/libpam0g-dev))

Comment: Поставил  ```libpam0g-dev``` и вроде пошла компиляция. Спасибо

Comment: Сторонний вопрос: а почему не взять себе Buildroot и не сконфигурировать «под себя»?